# Confirming form after form has been submitted and validated in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a appointment form once it has been submitted you get a confirmation of the data you've filled in, The confirmation has a button that when pressed on it it should insert the data to the database.

My question is, how to implement the button on the confirmation so it inserts?

---

I was thinking of making a if statement as this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

}
```

---

And within that if statement another if statement that would check if the button on the confirmation had been submitted so i could use the entitymanager to insert it in the database.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

  if () {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($appointment);
        $entityManager->persist($customer);
        $entityManager->flush();
  }

}
```

---

The appointment form:
[The appointment form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmgOa.png)

The confirmation template:
[The confirmation template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGwE.png)

---

The appointment form:

```
{% block body %}

    <p>new appointment</p>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Plan In') }}</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

The confirmation template

```
{% block body %}

    <p>confirm appointment</p>

    <p>{{ customer_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ customer_phone }}</p>
    <p>{{ customer_email }}</p>
    <hr>
    <p>{{ barber_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ treatment_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ appointment_date|date('d-m-Y') }}</p>
    <p>{{ appointment_time|date('H:i') }}</p>

    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Confirm') }}</button>

{% endblock %}
```

---

If there is any confusion within my question please ask for clarification, And if you believe there is a better way of achieving what I want to achieve please suggest so.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your confirmation template isn't a form, best way to send data to a controller may be by sending it with an Ajax request. When clicking your button, send a request :

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
            // guetting all the data you want to send
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    // url is the route of your controller action 
                    url: url,
                    processData: true,
                    data: objectYouWantToSend
                    beforeSend: function(request) {console.log('sending someting');},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("nailed it");
                        // some logic you want to do
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                        console.log('ooops, sometin went wrong');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Then, in your controller, you can get the data with :

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            // getting data from request
            $data = $request->request;

            // symfo logic you want to do


            return new JsonResponse(array($status => $message));

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, however i have 1 form which i get the data from in another template and i need to call that button in the controller so i can insert it. I dont have 2 forms i think you read wrongly :)

Comment: Yes sorry, just edited my post, tell me if this can help you

Comment: enckao thank you for your response, Once I get home I will try your solution thanks in advance.

Comment: no problem, don't mind to ask there if you still need help, will try to help

Comment: It says that $ is not defined, It doesnt reach the id btn.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, the code I linked was Jquery, you need to add the Jquery CDN in your base templete head, it may work with this

Answer (score 0):

we can solve this without using `javascript`.
 we're going to handle the submit by forwarding the form to the confirm action

```
/**
 * @Route("/submit", name="form-submit")
 */
public function submitApp(){
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
     return $this->redirectToRoute('confirm',[form])
  }
  return $this->render('appo.html.twig', [
        'form' => 'form',
    ]);    
}
```

Once the confirm the is clicked we're going to persist the value.

```
/**
 * @Route("/confirm", name="form-confirm")
 */
public function confirmApp()
{
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      // if configrm is pressed 
      $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $entityManager->persist($appointment);
      $entityManager->persist($customer);
      $entityManager->flush();
  }
}
```

in the view

```
 {{ form_widget(myFieldName, { ‘disabled’:’disabled’ }) }}
```

to display values of the form restricted `ReadOnly`

**If you really want to implement a custom template in the confirm page without using the `form` you can get values from `form` like this:**

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

Assign the values with setters into your object like this

```
$app = new Apportionment();
$app->setCustomer_name($form->get('customer_name')->getData());
```

then persist the value if the confirm is pressed.

```
$entityManager->persist($appointment);
$entityManager->flush();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Mili, thanks for the answer firstly. The ```('confirm',[form])``` seems like a outdated constant any advice?

Comment: And how would I get the button if the confirm isn't a form? Because i use the getData(); i can't check when its submitted or not.

Comment: You're forwarding the form data to the confirm view , and if i understand right you have only one form, so when you press save and the data is stored it's and gos to the if form condition, what do you mean outdated ?